# How does an AND gate behave in this situation?

Tags: digital-logic

I'm a beginner and I want to know how a logic gate circuit works:

[image]

Will the led turn on just when I press the 2 switches? Or I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: Please use a more explanatory title, like: "How does AND gate behaves in this situation?"

Comment: ok, it was my first question here, i really don't know much about this site yet, sorry

Comment: Yes, the AND output will be high with both switches closed.  However, nothing is guaranteeing the level of the inputs when the switches are open, so the result could be anything.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The AND gate has a truth table that looks like this:

```
Input A  |  Input B  | Output
   0     |     0     |    0 
   0     |     1     |    0 
   1     |     0     |    0 
   1     |     1     |    1
```

So when both switches are on the output will be high. This circuit could be designed better for example using a resistor to limit the current flowing through the Light Emitting Diode (LED), and tying the inputs to either V+ or ground. So that you get more reliable operation.

An example would look like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fpkDDz.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

It could, and it could not.  It depends on the gate, and it depends on the LED.  It's also a bad idea, as there's a possibility of providing too much current and frying the LED.  You should have a resistor in series with the LED to limit the current at the very least.

Comment: yeah, i know, but, ignoring this kind of thing, supposing that the current is perfectly calculated, is this the way that a logic gat works?

Comment: For an AND gate, as you have specified in the picture- yes, when both inputs are set to 1/HIGH, you should get a 1/HIGH at the output, lighting the LED.  If this isn't happening, you should provide more information (a better diagram) so we can help figure out what the problem is.

Comment: actually i never built that circuit, i'm just studying by myself and trying to understand because i'm in the summer break (i'm brazilian). so, thanks for answering, and sorry about my bad english :P

Comment: You want to add two pull down resistors on the inputs.

Comment: why can't i add just one resistor after the logic gate?

Comment: @LeviTrevisan tak a look at Dean's circuit diagram.

Answer (score 1):

You want to add pull down resistors as @jippie pointed out between the switches and the inputs on the logic gate so that the gate's inputs will be stable. When the switch is closed, it should be clear that current will be flowing and that input will be at logic high (a 1 if you like). But now think about the voltage level that one of the inputs on that AND gate sees when the switch is open. It's probably not logic High, but it's not necessarily logic Low (a 0) either. It will very likely end up "floating" in a state somewhere between high and low, and behave unpredictably.

The Pull-down resistor's job is to nail that input to logic low/0 (Usually Ground) when the switch is open. You pick a relatively high resistance, like 10K ohm and have it going from the branch between the switch and the digital input to ground. That way, when the switch is open, the AND gate sees a solid logic 0 at that input. When the switch is closed, the wire going from the voltage source, through the switch, to the input, has such a lower impedance than the branch with the resistor to ground that the gate sees a logic 1 at that input.

In any real application, you want a resistor in series with the LED as well, but for a different reason. As @TheNoonMoose rightly points out, too much current will turn a poor little LED into a useless lump with a puff of smoke. This is a separate issue from pull-up and pull-down resistors though.

Comment: you don't wanna release the magic smoke...